# How do I get the URL of a Core Data persistent store for deletion?

Tags: ios, core-data

I wish to call the function `persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(...)`. I'm creating my container with it like this `NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyProject")` what I would like to know is how to get the URL of the persistentStore for use in the first call, in Swift preferably.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `NSPersistentContainer` has a `persistentStoreDescriptions` property.

That array describes the stores loaded in the coordinator, including their URL.

Comment: If I want to delete everything, do I just iterate through them, calling `destroyPersistentStoreAtURL(...)` with each of them?

Comment: @JoshParadroid if that’s what you want. But usually you’ll only have 1 item in that array.